# MikTeX error "Some Postscript specials could not be rendered" when using package prerex

Tags: miktex, postscript

As part of a larger project I am using package `prerex` to generate a chapter dependency chart.  Within MiKTeX I am running `latex --src -specials` on what is essentially the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{prerex}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{diagheight}{100}
\begin{chart} 
\reqhalfcourse 30, 95:{}{Chapter Dependency Chart}{}
\end{chart}
\end{document}
```

The chart is created but together with error message "Some PostScript specials could not be rendered".  This then results in insuperable problems connected with calls to `\include` within other project files.

The log file is here:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29) (preloaded format=latex 2020.7.9)  11 JUL 2020 21:45
entering extended mode
**./sampleChartprerex.tex
(sampleChartprerex.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@chapter=\count168
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@subparagraph=\count173
\c@figure=\count174
\c@table=\count175
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/prerex\prerex.sty
Package: prerex 2019/11/15 v6.8.0 LaTeX style for prerequisite charts, pgf vers
ion
\unit=\skip49

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/relsize\relsize.sty
Package: relsize 2013/03/29 ver 4.1
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count176
\calc@Bcount=\count177
\calc@Adimen=\dimen135
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen136
\calc@Askip=\skip50
\calc@Bskip=\skip51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count178
\calc@Cskip=\skip52
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks15
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen137
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen138

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box45
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex")
Package: pgfrcs 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
Package: pgf 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen139
\Gin@req@width=\dimen140
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen141
\pgf@y=\dimen142
\pgf@xa=\dimen143
\pgf@ya=\dimen144
\pgf@xb=\dimen145
\pgf@yb=\dimen146
\pgf@xc=\dimen147
\pgf@yc=\dimen148
\pgf@xd=\dimen149
\pgf@yd=\dimen150
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count179
\c@pgf@countb=\count180
\c@pgf@countc=\count181
\c@pgf@countd=\count182
\t@pgf@toka=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks22
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count183
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvips.def

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-dvips.def"
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-postscr
ipt.def"
File: pgfsys-common-postscript.def 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@objectcount=\count184
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count185
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count186
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen151
\pgfmath@count=\count187
\pgfmath@box=\box46
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count188
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen152
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen153
\pgf@picminy=\dimen154
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen155
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen156
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen157
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen158
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen159
\pgf@xx=\dimen160
\pgf@xy=\dimen161
\pgf@yx=\dimen162
\pgf@yy=\dimen163
\pgf@zx=\dimen164
\pgf@zy=\dimen165
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen166
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen167
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen168
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen169
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfpic=\box47
\pgf@hbox=\box48
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box49
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count189
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen170
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen171
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen172
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen173
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen174
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@max=\dimen175
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count190
\pgf@shadingcount=\count191
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box50
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex"
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.
tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box51
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen176
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen177
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen178
\pgffor@skip=\dimen179
\pgffor@stack=\toks26
\pgffor@toks=\toks27
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count192
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen180
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen181
\tikz@lasty=\dimen182
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen183
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen184
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen185
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen186
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen187
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen188
\tikz@figbox=\box52
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box53
\tikz@tempbox=\box54
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box55
\tikztreelevel=\count193
\tikznumberofchildren=\count194
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count195
\tikz@fig@count=\count196

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count197
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count198
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count199
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count266

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.meta.c
ode.tex"
File: pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfarrowinset=\dimen189
\pgfarrowlength=\dimen190
\pgfarrowwidth=\dimen191
\pgfarrowlinewidth=\dimen192
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekey
s.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.st
y
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen193
\Hy@linkcounter=\count267
\Hy@pagecounter=\count268

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count269
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `raiselinks' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4717.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count270

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen194

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.st
y
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count271
\Field@Width=\dimen195
\Fld@charsize=\dimen196
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6365.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/atbegshi\atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
)
\Hy@abspage=\count272
\c@Item=\count273
\c@Hfootnote=\count274
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (default): hdvips.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hdvips.def"
File: hdvips.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for dvips

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pdfmark.def"
File: pdfmark.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
\pdf@docset=\toks28
\pdf@box=\box56
\pdf@toks=\toks29
\pdf@defaulttoks=\toks30
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count275
\Fld@listcount=\count276
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count277

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilech
eck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/atveryend\atveryend.sty
Package: atveryend 2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecoun
ter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip53
))
\c@@myangle=\count278
\c@@inangle=\count279
\c@@dx=\count280
\c@@dy=\count281
\c@@gridwidth=\count282
\c@@gridright=\count283
\c@@gridheight=\count284
\c@@gridtop=\count285
\c@@diagwidth=\count286
\c@diagheight=\count287
\pgf@layerbox@arrows=\box57
\pgf@layerboxsaved@arrows=\box58
\pgf@layerbox@courses=\box59
\pgf@layerboxsaved@courses=\box60
\pgf@layerbox@grid=\box61
\pgf@layerboxsaved@grid=\box62
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvips.def"
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2020-06-29 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count288
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box64
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box65
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count289
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count290
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count291
)
(sampleChartprerex.aux)
\openout1 = `sampleChartprerex.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box66
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 5.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitles
tring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count292
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 5.
 (sampleChartprerex.out) (sampleChartprerex.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `sampleChartprerex.out'.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 8.

Overfull \hbox (16.89606pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
[][][]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--10

 []

[1

]
Overfull \vbox (39.7233pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []


[2] [3]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 10.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 10.
 (sampleChartprerex.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 10.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 10.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `sampleChartprerex.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 10.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15670 strings out of 480791
 307228 string characters out of 2905206
 570801 words of memory out of 3000000
 31398 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532647 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 59i,14n,71p,433b,943s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on sampleChartprerex.dvi (3 pages, 13748 bytes).
```

Comment: I don't get this warning. Show the log-file from your example.

Comment: Is your miktex fully updated? In both miktex admin mode and miktex user mode (you use files from both)

Comment: Regarding updates, I was unaware of the distinction.  Thanks for this.  There were, in fact, three available updates from the miktek console running in admin mode, none in user (non-admin?) mode.  Updating did not make for a difference, however.  The same error is raised.